# On a derivative involving the Riemann zeta function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, riemann-zeta-function

Let $n$ be a positive real number. Can the equality

$$\dfrac{d^{n}}{ds^{n}}\Big[s^{n-1}\ln\Big(\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma\Big(1+\frac{s}{2}\Big)\Big)\Big]\Bigg|_{s=1} = - \dfrac{d^{n}}{ds^{n}}\Big[s^{n-1}\ln\Big(\ln(s-1)\zeta(s)\Big)\Big]\Bigg|_{s=1}$$

be possible for any positive real $n$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function and $\Gamma(s)$ is the usual gamma function in number theory ?

My approach was by fractional calculus (to accommodate all reals), but I did not complete it since it appeared terribly malicious too me. I'm wondering if there can be some shorter and more intuitive way? Even a long complete proof by fractional calculus will still be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the functional equation of $\zeta$?

Comment: Maybe an expansion of all the functions involved in Taylor series could help.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, wouldn't that make things *extra* messy ?

Comment: One doesn't have $\zeta(s)=\zeta(1-s)$ but $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ with $\xi(s)=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Perhaps, but it allows to perform computations.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry i meant the xi-function in the earlier comment.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, you could really help by making a sketch of the calculations, to me it appears immensely complicated since we are dealing with fractional derivatives.

Comment: Or you can write $\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(1+s/2)=s\xi(s)/\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, please could you make some sketches of your suggested calculations ? I think that would really help.

Comment: Please also see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1946892/300579

Comment: The "usual gamma function in number theory" is usually denoted by $\Gamma(s)$, no?

Comment: There are different approaches to fractional differentiation; could you indicate in your post which one you have in mind?

Comment: @ToddTrimble, on the fractional differentiation approach that i applied, i used: $$\frac{d^{a}}{dx^{a}}x^k = \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k-a+1)}x^{k-a}$$, and it doesn't appear to yield much. Perhaps you could help ? Remark: the MSE post seems easier to deal with, since it doesn't involve $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: I can't be of much help, as this is not my area; sorry. I thought it might help others who are looking at your question though. (If I had to throw out a guess, it might be to consider something like $(D^\alpha f)(z_0) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{2\pi i} \int_{|z - z_0| = r} \frac{f(z)}{(z - z_0)^{\alpha + 1}} dz$, but that's only a guess.) Also, it might help if you expanded your post to explain motivation or why you are interested, or the context in which others are interested in fractional derivatives of functions related to $\zeta(s)$.

Answer (score 1):

Many basic complex-analyis misunderstandings here.

- First of all, $\frac{d^n}{ds^n}$ means $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (otherwise you have to define it). Then you probably wanted to write the Laurent series at $s=1$ of $\log \zeta(s)$. Unfortunately, $s=1$ is a branch point of $\log \zeta(s)$ not an isolated singularity, so it doesn't have a Laurent series there, and the coefficients you wrote on the RHS don't exist.
- Then I can guess you wanted instead to consider $\dfrac{d^{n}}{ds^{n}}\Big[s^{n-1}\log\Big((s-1)\zeta(s)\Big)\Big]\Bigg|_{s=1}$ since $\log\Big((s-1)\zeta(s)\Big)$ is analytic at $s=1$,  but it also means $\log\Big((s-1)\zeta(s)\Big)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k (s-1)^k$ (for $|s-1| < 3$) and hence $\dfrac{d^{n}}{ds^{n}}\Big[s^{n-1}\log\Big((s-1)\zeta(s)\Big)\Big]\Bigg|_{s=1} = \dfrac{d^{n}}{ds^{n}}\Big[\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k(s-1)^{n+k-1}\Big]\Bigg|_{s=1}  $
  $=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{n!}(s-1)^{k-1}\Bigg|_{s=1} = c_1$

  where $c_1 = \frac{d}{ds}\Big[\log\Big((s-1)\zeta(s)\Big)\Big]\Bigg|_{s=1} = \lim_{s \to 1} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac{1}{s-1} = \gamma$ (the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant))
- In the same way $\log\Big(\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma\Big(1+\frac{s}{2}\Big)\Big) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (s-1)^n$ and $\dfrac{d^{n}}{ds^{n}}\Big[(s-1)^{n-1}\log\Big(\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma\Big(1+\frac{s}{2}\Big)\Big)\Big]\Bigg|_{s=1} = a_{1} = -\frac{\log(\pi)}{2}+ \frac{\Gamma'(3/2)}{2\Gamma(3/2)}$ [$ -\frac{\log(\pi)}{2}+1+\frac{\Gamma'(1/2)}{2\Gamma(1/2)}=-\frac{\log(\pi)}{2}+1- \frac{2\log(2)+\gamma}{2} \ne -\gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Special_values)
- Finally, note that the coefficients $c_n$ of the Taylor series of $\log\Big((s-1)\zeta(s)\Big)$ around $s=1$ are given by $$c_n = \frac{1}{n!}\dfrac{d^{n}}{ds^{n}}\Big[\log\Big((s-1)\zeta(s)\Big)\Big]\Bigg|_{s=1}$$

Comment: actually, the coefficients on the right hand side are *known* to exist, hence i'm not sure what you mean. Anyway, does your answer suggest that the equality is impossible ?

Comment: And please *check* that i clearly stated that $n$ is a positive real number, hence not necessarily any integer.

Comment: @SPD you need to define $d^n/dn$ for $n \not \in \mathbb{N}$, and there is almost no interesting reason for looking at the fractional derivative of functions related to $\zeta(s)$, secondly I told you your formula is unclear, and one as to guess what you meant. Now I see that a possiblity is that you meant $\log(\log((s-1)\zeta(s))) = F(s)$ that is holomorphic  at $s=1$. Hence (for $n \in \mathbb{N}$) your RHS is $F'(1)$. can you compute it ?

Comment: it also seems that you're considering *only* the case when $n$ is a positive integer, which doesn't *completely* address the question.

Comment: ''There is almost no interesting for looking at the fractional derivative involving $\zeta(s)$''. To me this sounds like your own perception which you shouldn't necessarily assume to hold for everyone.

Comment: And what i wrote is exactly what i meant, not otherwise.

Comment: @SPD I said something dumb, at $s\to 1$ : $\log((s-1)\zeta(s)) \to 0$ so $\log(\log((s-1)\zeta(s)))$ has a branch point at $s=1$.

Comment: Can you tell me where the $\log(\log((s-1)\zeta(s))$ is coming from or why you even considered it ?